# 'Unexpected end of JSON input' error while working with Shopify webhooks

Tags: shopify, webhooks, shopify-app, shopify-api-node

I've created an app and try to register for webhooks, and then fetch the list of all webhooks.
I use this code for this (`/server/middleware/auth.js`):

```
const webhook = new Webhook({ session: session });
      webhook.topic = "products/update";
      webhook.address = "https://api.service.co/items/update";
      webhook.format = "json";
      console.log("registering products/update");
      try {
        await webhook.save({
          update: true,
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }

      const webhookSecond = new Webhook({ session: session });
      webhookSecond.topic = "products/create";
      webhookSecond.address = "https://api.service.co/items/webhooks";
      webhookSecond.format = "json";

      console.log("registering products/create");

      try {
        await webhookSecond.save({
          update: true,
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }

      console.log("getting all webhooks");
      try {
        let webhooks = await Webhook.all({
          session: session,
        });
        console.log(webhooks);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
```

Everything works fine for a development store. However, when I try to launch this script on a third-party customer store, then I get this error:

```
HttpRequestError: Failed to make Shopify HTTP request: FetchError: invalid json response body at https://shopname.myshopify.com/admin/api/2022-04/webhooks.json reason: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

The app permissions/scopes are: `read_checkouts, read_orders, read_inventory, read_products, read_customers`

I got this error 3 times, even for `Webhook.all`.

Could you please tell me what can cause this error, and how could it be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was caused by the lack of access provided by the owner of the store to my collaborator developer account. `Manage settings` access was required.